# reusing common sections in a webpage

Tags: html, layout

Ok, I have searched on web and stackoverflow too, but no success.

I just want the code of header, nav-bars, footers etc. to be reused. I just want them to sit at their own respective files and then I want all other file to link these files.

How will we do these in html5 way.

Can someone please help me?

Thanks
Raja

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 include file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401113/html5-include-file)

Comment: Do you have a web server? The simplest way are server-side includes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really possible with plain HTML. For reusing HTML chunks in your web page you basically have two options: 
1. Server side templates via PHP, Twig, Smarty or the likes. 
2. Or you can do client side templates with MustacheJS, Jade or Handlebars.

Comment: How about sitemesh? will it do?

Comment: You mean this http://wiki.sitemesh.org/display/sitemesh/Home ? Yes it should work.

Comment: yes, the same wiki. Btw, Handlebars looked lot simpler. Thanks for that.