# use part of html-body through all the pages

Tags: css, html, highlight

possibly the title is not-so-clear, as I am not sure how to explain this.
I am creating my html (one time work, so not using java. just plain html with css).

Consider this schematic diagram(`Pic 1`).
The left panel and footer is *almost* same thorough out the website's all pages, it contents the link to other pages in the website.

```
|================================|
||-------||------------||------| |
||LEFT   ||CENTER      ||RIGHT | |
||PANEL  ||PANEL       ||PANEL | |
||_______||____________||______| |
||_______________________________|
||  FOOTER                       |
||_______________________________|
|================================|
```

Pic.1  the webpage layout

```
|------------------------|
|                        |
|link to pA              |
|link to pB              |
|                        |
|current link highlited  |
|------------------------|
```

Pic2. layout of left panel

but with my present knowledge, I have to change all pages if I try to make any change in the left panel and footer. Is it possible to write this left panel in a seperate file, and include it where needed?

Also, possibly a separate question, but linked, assuming writing the left panel in separate file is possible. is it possible to highlight currently visiting pagelink?(see `Pic 2`)

Answer (score 0):

`EDIT`
I am sorry, I did not pay enough attention. You are not using PHP?
In that case take a look at
[HTML5 include file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401113/html5-include-file)

I could not find a way to share data between main page and included file though. Perhaps if possible, in your included file you may use a `#` tag, e.g. `mypage.html#hello` and parse it with JavaScript to find out which page you are visiting.

---

You practically answer your own question. Simply take out the HTML code and put it in a separate file and include it where it originally was.

Say your code is

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="left-panel">
        <div id="links etc"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="another"></div>
</div>
```

You would take the `left-panel` part and put in a separate file and include it where it was.

`left-panel.php`

```
<div id="left-panel">
    <div id="links etc"></div>
</div>
```

Original file

```
<div id="main">
    <?php include 'left-panel.php'; ?>
    <div id="another"></div>
</div>
```

To know which page you currently are visiting you could be using a variable. Say in each page you put `<?php $page = 'shop'; ?>` and inside `left-panel.php` use if-statements like:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="page1.php" <?php if($page == 'page1') echo 'class="active"'; ?>>Page1</li>
    <li><a href="page2.php" <?php if($page == 'page2') echo 'class="active"'; ?>>Page2</li>
</ul>
```

To avoid a bunch of if-statements, you could place your pages in an array and loop them:

```
<ul>
<?php
$pages = array('page1' => 'Page1', 'page2' => 'Page2', 'page3' => 'Page3');
foreach($pages as $file => $name) {
    echo '<li><a href="'.$file.'" '.($page == $file ? 'class="active"' : '').'>'.$name.'</a></li>';
}
?>
```