# Include HTML markup from file with pure HTML and suppress the creation of another docment structure

Tags: html

I have a HTML file where I'd like to include the HTML markup from other files, for example:

sub-content-1.html:
`<div>This is the <b>sub-content</b> that should be included</div>`

I've tried the following solutions from this answer: [HTML5 include file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13770307/1265240):

```
<object name="included" type="text/html" data="sub-content-1.html"></object>
```

and:

```
<embed type="text/html" src="sub-content-1.html">
```

The problem I have is that it not only includes the content of the html file, but also generates an **additional `HTML/HEAD/BODY`-structure inside the object (embed) element** and wraps the content within. Therefore, the included content is treated as a separate document and doesn't use my `css` styles. I didn't specify this html-structure in the file (only the content) and I don't want it to be treated as a separate document.

I tried specifying the MIME type as `text/plain`, hoping that it would load it as-is. But still, the html-structure is generated and the content gets wrapped within a `<pre>`-tag.

So what I want HTML to do is just to include the markup, without the extra document-structure being generated. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

If you use jQuery, you can use the [`.load()`](https://api.jquery.com/load/) function.

If not, you can use an XMLHttpRequest object and load the content into the DOM via AJAX.