# Access children of HTML5 <object> with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, jersey

I'm building a web application and extracted the code of my navigation menu in a separate file. Afterwards, I include the menu with the HTML `<object>` element in all of my pages as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401113/html5-include-file). This ensures that I can modify the navigation without touching any other files.

However, I have a problem of dynamically modifying the elements of my menu using jQuery (or d3.js). Here is a very small toy example to reproduce the problem:

**nav.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
<body>
  <h1>Title of the navigation menu.</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      // this code does not work
      $("h1").text("New Title Of The Menu");

      // this code does work
      $("h2").text("New Title Of The Website");
    });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>

    <!-- include the menu code here -->
    <object id="navigation" class="navigationObject" name="navigation"
    type="text/html" data="nav.html" width="100%" height="100px"></object>

<h2>Title of the website</h2> 

</body>
</html>
```

It seems that jQuery (and also d3.js) have a problem of selecting elements of embedded objects. Is it possible to select these elements?

Alternatively, is there a better solution to extract the code for the navigation menu in a separate file? The setup of my web application is as follows:

- Client side purely written in JavaScript using jQuery and d3.js
- Server side written in Java
- REST for client-server communication using Jersey 2.6.

Comment: The content of the `object` is in a different DOM -- DOM selectors won't cross DOMs. What you could try is to select the root of the other DOM and then select from that: `d3.select(d3.select("#navigation").documentElement).select("h1")`.

Comment: Thanks very much for the comment. Unfortunately, this doesn't work either.