# Ability to use a single html that stands as an 'include' to another html page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I was searching around for an answer to this question but I can't seem to find the exact "words" or "phrases" to find relevant answers.

My question is, is it possible to have an ability to use a single html that stands as an "include" to another html page?

**Example:** Being able to use one file containing CSS styles so the same file can appear on every page of the site automatically that I include it on.

I made a template that has an extension of `.html` that contains only my header and footer for the whole theme of the site. Normally, I would copy and paste the contents of these templates to each new html page then add in the unique body content for that page.

What I would like to do is make a template that has an extension of `.html` containing only my header and footer so I can do something like `include template.html` which automatically would put the content of the `template.html` page on each page so I don't have to copy and paste each time. I am finding it harder and harder to update/maintain each page of the site that contains the header and footer script because I have to find and replace each instance of those scripts when changes are made and must be propagated throughout the site.

I know that html does not actually have an `include` function but I think there should be a way around this through other languages such as PHP or even JavaScript? I just am curious if its possible and if so, how?

Comment: If PHP is your language of choice, look into [include()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php). Your syntax is actually correct: `include 'template.html';` But that statement must be included in a PHP file, eg. `index.php`

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, Marcus! ... I honestly agree with you regarding that matter but my main question would be... won't a included html file that contains my <head> , Navbar and Footer have compatibility issues with the style i am making with the current document? Example: footer loaded earlier so it will be above my content area?

Comment: It sounds like what you're after is a template engine such as [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) for PHP

Comment: Split your header and footer into separate files. Then include them within your main template wherever you need them. `index.php`: `<html><?php include 'header.html';?> ... more stuff on page <?php include 'footer.html'; ?> </html>` Something to that effect, anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List common html reference tags in one file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50221796/list-common-html-reference-tags-in-one-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a few different options. With PHP you could do something like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>

            <h1>Welcome to my home page!</h1>
            <p>Some text.</p>
            <p>Some more text.</p>
            <?php include 'footer.php';?>

        </body>
    </html>
```

See [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp).

With AngularJS you could use something like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <body ng-app="">
            <div ng-include="'myFile.htm'"></div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

See [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_includes.asp).

With just HTML5 you could try something like this:

```
    <object name="foo" type="text/html" data="foo.inc"></object>
```

See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401113/html5-include-file).

Does that help answer your question?

Comment: so basically in order for this to work for me.. i must: 
1. Load the angular.js first
2. Put slice the "template" in to parts in a sense that navbar is seperated from the footer right? correct me if i am wrong... 

Thanks!

Comment: AngularJS is a whole other beast in itself. If you're still figuring out the logic behind including files into a standard template, I'd focus on the PHP `include()` approach until you get the hang of it. Then branch out into frameworks. 'Cause what's the point in loading an entire framework simply to include a header and footer? Unless you're going to continue using/taking advantage of the AngularJS lib within your development, don't bother with it right now.

Comment: I agree with @Marcus. And I feel like you already said something about PHP.  All I used for a while was PHP includes for headers and footers and they worked great.

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking is possible in differents ways:

**frame and iframe**

take a look at this two tags

- frame : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frame.asp
- iframe : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

I do not recommend this solution because "frame" is not supported in HTML5 and "iframe" is made to include other website in a website, not part of a website. You will not be able to add CSS/JS to code in "iframe" tag.

**back end solution**

Depending on what kind of website you are working on you can include other file. For exemple in php:

```
include('youcode.html');
```

**HTML5 solution**

You can also use the "object" tag :

```
<object width="100%" height="500px" data="snippet.html"></object>
```

this is probably your best choice, see : http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_object.asp

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done via HTML, you can either do a PHP include or use this W3 schools example:

http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp

PHP example
template.html rename to template.php

```
<html>
<?php include template.php ?>
</html>
```

Comment: so i must slice the template up for this to work right? thanks in advance

Comment: It depends on the template really, I usually have a header and a footer.

The header will contain any side bars.