# List common html reference tags in one file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, code-duplication

I am wondering if there is a way to store `<link>` or `<script>` reference elements required for multiple web pages(AngularJS, Fonts, JQuery, Scripts, Google Analytics, Etc.) in a file and then import that file into all of my HTML files(e.g. I can change a file in some place and since it is referenced in all of my pages it will update all of those pages).

Comment: What about php include a file from root of your server?

Comment: You'll probably want to use a tool like gulp to build your pages from templates, this would allow you to have standard imports and even meta tags, feel free to see how I did my site for reference (https://github.com/jrtapsell/personal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [HTML Imports](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/imports/) would support this use case, but it is currently in the draft phase.

```
<link rel="import" href="myfile.html">
```

If you're interested in using this functionality now there are polyfills that support it. Another option that has been mentioned is to use a template system to add the necessary dependencies to the HTML when the page is requested, or even at build time.

Comment: Although this is exactly what I am looking for chrome gave me this warning when I tried it:  [Deprecation] Styling master document from stylesheets defined in HTML Imports is deprecated, and is planned to be removed in M67, around May 2018. Please refer to (link) for possible migration paths,  I am wondering if it is anything to worry about

Comment: I have not personally used HTML Imports, but that does sound like cause for concern and you should follow the migration path if possible. If you plan on using a polyfill you may not have any issues, in it's current state this functionality isn't even supported across browsers without using a polyfill so that may be your only option if you choose to use this functionality.

Comment: Is there any way to get the text content or HTML content of a file and then manually import it with javascript?

Comment: It doesn't really even have to be a file if there is any way to have a master file and slave files that copy all of the tags off of the master that would work too.  I really just want one central place that I can add something like a font or something.

Comment: This feature is, in fact, in the process of being deprecated and only partially works, I tried it with reCAPTCHA and it works on some pages, but not on others.