# "Masterpage"-Layout with jQuery Mobile in a PhoneGap app

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

Is it somehow possible to create something like a masterpage (asp.net) in jQuery Mobile?
I'm developing an mobile app (using phonegap if its important) and there I have the same header and footer (some buttons to navigate in the app) at all pages.
What I want to do is to create this footer just once... not in each div (page container).

Greetings

edit: thats the markup as I want it to be, but displayed is only page1 or page2 without header/footer

```
<div data-role="header">
        <h1>Header</h1>
</div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <div data-role="page" id="page1" data-title="Page 1">
            Page 1
        </div>
        <div data-role="page" id="page2" data-title="Page 2">
            Page 2
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="#page1">Page 1</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#page2">Page 2</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: This feature is in proposal stage. Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875404/why-does-html5-not-include-a-way-of-loading-local-html-into-the-document

Comment: HTML "includes" as in PHP for example are maybe interesting but not what I'm looking for... I could use an iFrame also for now.
What I want to do is to use jQuery Mobile navigation as its provided but i dont want to change the whole page but just a part of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After coming back to this problem I have decidet to use backbone.js. This is a javascript MVC framework.

For more informations see:

http://backbonejs.org/

http://backbonetutorials.com/

Also something I have found during my research:

http://kmalakoff.github.com/knockback/
Have not tried it yet, but it sounds very nice. This framework combines backbone.js and knockout.js (an MVVM framework) together.

Hope this helpes other peoples with the same problem!

Answer (score 1):

You could look at this good tutorial [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/94e7fded-7162-445e-8ceb-97a2140866a9/entry/dynamic_page_loading_for_phonegap1?lang=zh) which explains how to structure your code so you reuse the header and footer.

It basically creates a wrapper method called Load which dynamically loads a page into the dom, at a given location (usually your content placeholder).

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Asp.Net to develop your JQM, merely use the the Asp.Net master page. The body could look something like ...

```
<body>

<div data-role="page" data-theme="c" id="pgMaster">
    <div data-role="header" data-nobackbtn="true" data-theme="a">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PageTitleContent" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-id="nav" data-theme="a">
        <h4 style="font-size: 75%">
            <%= AppCode.Common.CGlobals.CopyRight %>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ScriptContent" runat="server" />
</div>
</body>
```

My site at http://Cta.yyyz.com is built using Aps.Net with `enableviewstate=false` in `web.Config` so your are really creating basic html pages - no bloat.

Comment: I'm developing a mobile application with PhoneGap (as explained ;) ).
There you dont have a server part for your pages... you have to develop html+javascript which gets deployed on the mobile device. So the .html and .js files are "hard" on the device => no asp.net =/