# Common Menu/Masthead for websites using HTML5

Tags: html

When learned to make JSP pages, I was taught to use a common menu page separate from all other pages and then import the menu page to each page using `<jsp:directive.include file="menu.jspx" />`.

Is there a similar way to do this in HTML5? Or is there a better way to include a common menu/masthead on every page using HTML5?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does HTML5 not include a way of loading local HTML into the document?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875404/why-does-html5-not-include-a-way-of-loading-local-html-into-the-document)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, html5 doesn't do this.

What you were doing in JSP was a server-side include.
What you are asking for is a client-side include, those don't exist in html5.

I you had a good reason for loading something client-side, you could use javascript.
Look into AJAX. A lot of .js libraries have good support, to make it easier.
jQuery for example has  a load() function which takes some of the pain away.

I don't recommend using something like that for a navigation menu though.
Server-side includes would be better.

If you're simply working on a small project, maybe you're doing it locally, and you just want to make it so you don't have to copy-paste chunks of the page everywhere, php is an easy way to do it.

Use something like XAMPP to run php on your machine in an easy-to-follow way.
Then use php's include function, as demonstrated here: [PHP Include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) to do what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm working on a small company website and am looking for the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to do this is to use Server Side Includes. Most servers support this.

[Further reading here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes)