# combining two pages in HTML

Tags: html

I'm creating a web site for an institute, since I'm new to this field I want to know whether I can create a page for header part(which containing the logo and the name of the institute) and  can I combine that page to each and every page I'm creating. If it is possible suggest me how can I combine the header part & newly created page..

Comment: Yes! you can use `iframes` or if you using `PHP` then use `require` and `include`

Comment: You can also jquery load function for load external page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does HTML5 not include a way of loading local HTML into the document?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875404/why-does-html5-not-include-a-way-of-loading-local-html-into-the-document)

Answer (score 4):

Surprisingly, there is no way to do that in straight HTML. Not even in HTML5.

If you are only creating a few pages, I suggest simply copy-pasting the content to each page's HTML file. Admittedly, that approach can quickly become a burden.

Some web servers will parse the HTML of a page before it is served out, look for a specific kind of HTML comment, and then interpret that as a command to insert the contents of another file. This feature is called "[server-side includes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes)" or "SSI". Some web servers, such as [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/), have this feature but turn it off by default due to security concerns.

If you are building [dynamic pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_web_page) where the HTML content being served is created on-the-fly with a programming language rather than read from pre-created disk files, then you can definitely include fragments of HTML using that programming language.

I suggest you do some additional study to build up your web authoring skills. One great source of training is the book "[Head First HTML with CSS & XHTML](http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfhtml/)" from O'Reilly Media, Inc.

Comment: There is more on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6878494/50049) which is answering not if, but _why_ HTML5 doesn't have more elegant means of seamless inclusion (speaking to the 'why must I use something like PHP just for partials?'). The 'seamless' iframe suggestion might be his best shot (and would be a perfectly good suggestion in your answer), it's like an iframe, but common DOM (no parent/child separation).

Comment: @TimPost As for why no standard inclusion feature, perhaps one big reason is security. SSI has been been a security risk in the past. [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/), for example, ships with SSI features turned off. Also, please vote to close this question, as you found a valid duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can do pull html code from different places and merge them with php. It's been years since I've done it, so I can't get into the particulars.